# JBoss Form based authentication automatically

Tags: java, authentication, gwt, jboss

A customer wants to reach a section (where a process with a wizard take place) of our app from their portal. It means, from their app (.Net) they want to have a link in order to reach a particular section of our app BUT! without having to go through the login process. Our app is a java app (GWT) and it uses FORM based authentication. I did an implementation with oAuth but they don't want login. I have not idea how to deal with this problem, I don't know if there is an alternative to get logged in by following the way they are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider to use  single sign on between your two applications. e. g. [CAS](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probalbly need Single Sign On.

If you choose to go the SSO way, there are some libraries that might help like JCIFS (useful for auth using NTLM) ,  Jespa. There is also Waffle, but this one works just on Windows server.

This article explore many options for JBoss:
https://dzone.com/articles/choosing-sso-your-jboss